# How to Redirect with React Router with function

Tags: reactjs

Every time that i try to redirect after pressing the edit button nothing happen and I get the error:
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

my code is:

```
const ClubInfo = ({ club:{ club, clubs }, getAllClubs, deleteClub, getCurrentClub }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllClubs();
  }, []);

  const handleEdit = (clubId) =>{
    getCurrentClub(clubId);
    return <Redirect to="/edit-club"/>
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h2>Clubs info</h2>
        <AddClubForm />
      <br></br>
    <table className="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Club Name</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {clubs.map( club => (
        <tr key={club._id}>
          <td>{club.clubName}</td>
          <td>
          <button onClick={()=>handleEdit(club._id)}>Edit</button>
          <button onClick={()=>deleteClub(club._id)}>Delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        ))}
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

ClubInfo.propTypes = {
  getAllClubs:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  deleteClub:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getCurrentClub:PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  profile :state.profile,
  club: state.club
});

export default connect( mapStateToProps , {getAllClubs, deleteClub, getCurrentClub} )(ClubInfo);
```

Comment: I'm a little confused; `getAllClubs` etc. are properties passed to the function, but you're trying to use them outside of the component in your `connect` call?

Comment: Yes, those functions are imported from a different file and they works well, But I don't succeed to redirect to a different page with 'handleEdit' function.